# Convert emacs org files to trac wiki

Tags: trac, org-mode

We just set up a trac system, before we used emac-org mode for manuals. Is there any conversation tools which is convert the org files to trac wiki format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try to set up `org-export-generic` ( http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html ) to match trac wiki format.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the .org files to MediaWiki using http://lumiere.ens.fr/~guerry/u/org-mediawiki.el

And then import those files into Trac following the instructions here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-i-convert-mediawiki-pages-to-trac

I haven't tested it and you might run into some problems. An alternative route could be via Moinmoin, I think there is some work going on regarding org2moinmoin and moinmoin2trac conversion.